# How to group using like statement

Tags: sql, sql-like

First time poster here, so be kind...

I am trying to create a new column that would group entries from another column that contain strings of text - for example, I would want entries containing "penny" in column A to have the value "Penny" in the new column, entries containing "nickel" in column A to have "Nickel", etc. I'm assuming I'd need to use a LIKE statement for this, as there may or may not be characters before/after the text strings I'm categorizing by (i.e. penny, nickel, etc).

It was recommended to me that I use a CASE statement, but I'm not sure that CASE statements can be used with LIKE. Anyone have any ideas? I'm by no means skilled with SQL, so I may be missing something, but will appreciate any assistance!

Comment: When you say _column_, do you mean it's in the same table or do you want to insert values into another table?

Comment: I would be creating a new column in the same table

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
UPDATE mytable
SET new_column = 
    (CASE
        WHEN original_column LIKE '%nickel%' THEN 'nickel'
        WHEN original_column LIKE '%penny%'  THEN 'penny'
        ELSE 'no match' END);
```

Your mileage on different SQL dialects may vary; this is off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you wish to do from the example presented, I believe you can just capitalize the first letter without using Like, which is a very expensive operator.

How about:

```
select metal, concat(upper(substr(metal,1,1)),substr(metal,2)) as CapitalizedMetal from t1
```

Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cd33/8)

Comment: That's not quite what I was going for - I was looking to create a new column to categorize my original column by whether they contain certain strings of text. Thank you for your input, though!